# Where in a bitcoin transaction can I store some data?

Tags: raw-data

I need to store some data in a transaction to the data can be stored in the blockchain.

In which field of the transaction I can store it?

Answer (score 1):

`createrawtransaction` can be used to store [data](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.16.3/rpc/rawtransactions/createrawtransaction/):

```
createrawtransaction [{"txid":"id","vout":n},...] {"address":amount,"data":"hex",...} ( locktime ) ( replaceable )

Create a transaction spending the given inputs and creating new outputs.
Outputs can be addresses or data.
Returns hex-encoded raw transaction.
Note that the transaction's inputs are not signed, and
it is not stored in the wallet or transmitted to the network.

Arguments:
1. "inputs"                (array, required) A json array of json objects
     [
       {
         "txid":"id",    (string, required) The transaction id
         "vout":n,         (numeric, required) The output number
         "sequence":n      (numeric, optional) The sequence number
       } 
       ,...
     ]
2. "outputs"               (object, required) a json object with outputs
    {
      "address": x.xxx,    (numeric or string, required) The key is the bitcoin address, the numeric value (can be string) is the BTC amount
      "data": "hex"      (string, required) The key is "data", the value is hex encoded data
      ,...
    }
3. locktime                  (numeric, optional, default=0) Raw locktime. Non-0 value also locktime-activates inputs
4. replaceable               (boolean, optional, default=false) Marks this transaction as BIP125 replaceable.
                             Allows this transaction to be replaced by a transaction with higher fees. If provided, it is an error if explicit sequence numbers are incompatible.

Result:
"transaction"              (string) hex string of the transaction

Examples:
> bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"address\":0.01}"
> bitcoin-cli createrawtransaction "[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]" "{\"data\":\"00010203\"}"
> curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "createrawtransaction", "params": ["[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]", "{\"address\":0.01}"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
> curl --user myusername --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "createrawtransaction", "params": ["[{\"txid\":\"myid\",\"vout\":0}]", "{\"data\":\"00010203\"}"] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://127.0.0.1:8332/
```